# Process the data after using str.split

Tags: python, python-3.x

I parse a `.txt` like this:

```
def parse_file(src):
    for line in src.readlines():
        if re.search('SecId', line):
            continue
        else:
            cols = line.split(',')
            Time = cols[4]
            output_file.write('{}\n'.format(
                          Time))
```

I think `cols` are lists that I could use index. Although it succeeds in printing out correct result as I want, there exists an out of range error:

> File "./tdseq.py", line 37, in parse_file
>         Time = cols[4]
>       IndexError: list index out of range
>       make: *** [all] Error 1

Data I use:

```
I10.FE,--,xx,xxxx,13450,tt,tt,tt,33,22,22:33:44
```

Comment: What does the file you're parsing look like? The problem is probably that cols is not a 5 element list.

Comment: @MatthewAdams I think each line has more than 5 columns. As I have mentioned, I can print out the fifth column, which is 13450, 13468...

Comment: @juju: nope, at least one of them doesn't.  Add a `print(cols)` to see the troublesome line, right before the error message.  [Wild guess: maybe there's an extra newline at the end?]

Comment: @DSM Problem fixed. len(cols) is 11. I forget to start a new line which makes them look like a lot of '1'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the data, it's hard to say.

Possible causes are that you are assuming 1-based indexing, when a line like:

`foo,bar,baz,qux`

would be indexed as positions 0,1,2,3 in the list.

By the way, **I highly recommend you to parse your file using the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module**.

Comment: Would you mind offering more information? The original data format is csv. Do I need to modify the program anywhere?

Comment: Yes, you should create a `csv.reader` object to parse the file.  Follow the examples in the link I have included.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an IndexError because `cols` doesn't have five elements in it.  Perhaps you have blank lines in the file?

Also note that getting lines from a file is better done with:

```
for line in src:
```

and if you are searching for a simple string, you don't need regexes, this will be enough:

```
if 'SecId' in line:
    continue
```

Comment: I think it would be `if 'SecId' not in line` for this case

Comment: I was replacing `if re.search("SecId", line):`

Comment: I have add the data. I think each line has more than 5 columns. As I have mentioned, I can print out the fifth column, which is 13450, 13468...

Comment: Right, but I was meaning to say that `if spam: continue; else:` is only a strange way of saying `if not spam:`

Comment: @wim: I was only willing to change so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use `len(cols)` check. Also your input data suggest that `time_index=3` not `4`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def parse_file(input_file):
    time_index = 3
    for line in input_file:
        if 'SecId' not in line:
            cols = line.split(',')
            if len(cols) > time_index:
               time = cols[time_index]
               print(time, file=output_file)
```